# jQuery - .toggle() triggering on page load

Tags: jquery

When I click on the word Directory, the up arrow image must change to down, and vice-versa when clicked again.

In this code, when the page loads, toggle is triggered.

```
$('#direct').click(function(){
     $('#arrow').attr('src','images/down_arrow_black.gif');
});


<div id="direct"><img src="images/up_arrow_black.gif" id="arrow" />Directory</div>
```

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the `.toggle()` method to make the toggle work, and `$()` to be sure it loads correctly:

```
$(function() {
    $('#direct').toggle(function(){
        $('#arrow').attr('src','images/down_arrow_black.gif');
    }, function() {
        $('#arrow').attr('src','images/up_arrow_black.gif');
    });
});
```

Comment: this is faster than `.toggle()`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069458/jquery-toggle-triggering-on-page-load/3069534#3069534

Answer (score 0):

if your jQuery wrapped in the following?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your toggle code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery 1.4

you can do it this way...

```
$('#direct').click(function(){
   $('#arrow').attr('src',function(i,src){            
        return src.indexOf('down')?'images/up_arrow_black.gif':'images/down_arrow_black.gif';
   });
});
```